# C Read until end of file

Tags: c

I currently have code that reads 4 lines and I want to be able to change that until EOF or my MAX const int value.  I can not get the !EOF to work right and was wondering how would I change my code to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct record{
    char name[2];
    int arrival_time;
    int job_length;
    int job_priority;
};

const int MAX = 40;

int main(void)
{
    struct record jobs[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","rb");

    while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", &jobs[i].name, &jobs[i].arrival_time,
                  &jobs[i].job_length, &jobs[i].job_priority) == 4 && i < MAX)
      i++;

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", jobs[j].name, jobs[j].arrival_time,
               jobs[j].job_length, jobs[j].job_priority);

    fclose(f);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to read until EOF, and don't know beforehand the total number of lines the `data.dat` file has, then you should consider dynamic storage for the struct `jobs` (a `malloc` and some `realloc` until end of file is reached).

Comment: It seems odd to use `fscanf` on a file opened in binary mode.  `fscanf` with an unqualified `"%s"` format is inherently unsafe unless you have complete control over what's in the input file; it reads a white-space delimited word of arbitrary length that can overflow your array.  Your termination condition, checking the value returned by `fscanf`, seems to be correct; if you have 4 data fields on each input line, it should work.  Can you show us what `data.dat` looks like?

Comment: My data.dat will look like this A1 3 3 3 on one line and then B1 4 4 4 and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
while (fscanf(f, "   %s   ", &etc) != EOF) {

}
```

Then use `feof(f)` to check if it was a `fscanf` error or actually `EOF`.

Comment: He's already checking whether `fscanf` returns 4 (the number of items requested); it should be reading up to 40 sets of items.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to do what you want, except:

```
char name[2];
```

Names will probably be longer than 1 character.

```
FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","rb");
```

You seem to be reading text (`"r"`) file, not binary (`"rb"`).

`&jobs[i].name` should be `jobs[i].name`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of the tests in your `while()` loop - you must test `i < MAX` *before* calling `fscanf()`, or else you'll potentially call it one too many times (you should also be passing `jobs[i].name` without the `&` to `fscanf`):

```
while (i < MAX && fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", jobs[i].name, &jobs[i].arrival_time,
              &jobs[i].job_length, &jobs[i].job_priority) == 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I would code like this:

```
for(i=0 ; i<MAX ; ++i) {
    fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", &jobs[i].name, &jobs[i].arrival_time,
           &jobs[i].job_length, &jobs[i].job_priority);
    if(ferror(f)  ||  feof(f)) break;
}
```

The key point is that, at the best of my knowledge, you cannot know that a file is come to end without trying to read it. That is the reason why I check feof() and ferror() after having read data.
At the end of the loop, the variable i contains the number of read data